# Touch issue on ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, selectionchanged

I have this `ListBox` in my xaml.

```
FIRST.XAML

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="newsList" 
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NewsListTemplate}"
   Margin="-2,86,2,0" SelectionChanged="openNewsViewer" 
   Height="361" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"
/>
```

The problem is that when I click first time on a list item, all ok, it calls `SECOND.XAML` correctly, but, when I go back to `FIRST.XAML` from `SECOND.XAML`, I'm unable to re-click at the same `ListBox` item!

But why?

Here C# code:

```
private void openNewsViewer(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listbox = (ListBox)sender;
    var entry = (ItemViewModel)listbox.SelectedItem;

    Navigate(entry.Link, entry.LineOne, true);
}

private void Navigate(string url, string title, bool showAppBar)
{
    var uri = "/NewsViewer.xaml?idx=" + url + "&title=" + title + "&appbar=" + (showAppBar == true ? "true" : "false");
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

It's all!

Any idea to solve this issue?
Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
Second click on the same row **NOT CALL** `openNewsViewer`. It could be a problem in XAML file?

Please help me.
thanks^2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your event fires when page is reloaded ( when your listbox is created the selectedItem is changed).

You can use ManipulationStarted event.

Comment: How I can use ManipulationStarted event? Have you an idea or more details? thanks

Comment: The same as you do with selection changed. Add this as a attribute to ListBox.

Comment: Ok, i added listbox.ManipulationStarted += new EventHandler<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(listbox_ManipulationStarted); and in method i added ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem = -1; But nothing different... how can i implement it in correct way? thanks.

Comment: dont add ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem = -1; to method. First off, test if event fires, the item is correct, Navigate has right arguments. If your event is fired properly and you still have the problem it maybe caused by xaml. Get rid off d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NewsListTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}". It is very hard to say what is wrong, I am just guessing.